# wxPython: frame class loads several commands AFTER it is called

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a function that runs a few intensive commands, so I made a `Spinner` class, which is just a simple window that appears with a `wx.Gauge` widget that pulses during loading.

The problem is that, when called in `Run`, the window doesn't appear until several seconds after it was initialized - `self.TriangulatePoints()` actually finishes before the window appears. Indeed, if I don't comment out `load.End()` (which closes the window), the `Spinner` instance will appear and immediately disappear.

I assume this has something to do with threading, and the program continues to run while `Spinner` initiates. Is this the case? And if so, can you pause progression of `Run()` until the `Spinner` window appears?

It should also be noted that running `time.sleep(n)` after calling `Spinner(...)` does not change when in the program sequence it appears on screen.

```
def Run(self, event):

    gis.points_packed = False
    gis.triangulated = False

    load = Spinner(self, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX) ^ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER) & (~wx.MINIMIZE_BOX))
    load.Update('Circle packing points...')

    gis.boundary(infile=gis.loaded_boundary)

    load.Pulse()

    self.GetPoints(None, show=False)

    load.Update("Triangulating nodes...")

    self.TriangulatePoints(None, show=True)

    load.End()

########################################################

class Spinner(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Spinner, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

        self.SetSize((300,80))
        self.SetTitle('Loading')

        process = "Loading..."
        self.font = wx.Font(pointSize = 12, family = wx.DEFAULT,
                   style = wx.NORMAL, weight = wx.BOLD,
                   faceName = 'Arial')

        self.process_txt = wx.StaticText(self, -1, process)
        self.process_txt.SetFont(self.font)

        self.progress = wx.Gauge(self, id=-1, range=100, pos=(10,30), size=(280,15), name="Loading")        
        self.Update(process)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def End(self):
        self.Close(True)

    def Update(self,txt):

        dc = wx.ScreenDC()
        dc.SetFont(self.font)

        tsize = dc.GetTextExtent(txt)
        self.process_txt.SetPosition((300/2-tsize[0]/2,10))

        self.process_txt.SetLabel(txt)
        self.progress.Pulse()

    def Pulse(self):
        self.progress.Pulse()
```

Comment: whats wrong with using wx.SplashScreen?

Comment: Right, well this is a small part of a much larger wx-based application - the `Run` function is actually called when a toolbar button is pressed. Since I have content in the main `wx.Frame`, it's important I have an external window appear.

Comment: https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `wx.Yield()` immediately after `load.Update('...')`, I was able to fix the problem.

I found the solution through a post that Robin Dunn ([@RobinDunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395984/robindunn)), one of the original authors of wxPython, [wrote in a Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/ozIUeqDteQM):

> As Micah mentioned the various yield functions are essentially a 
>   nested event loop that reads and dispatches pending events from the 
>   event queue.  When the queue is empty then the yield function returns.
>
> The reason [wx.Yield()] fixes the problem you are seeing is that your long 
>   running tasks are preventing control from returning to the main event 
>   loop and so the paint event for your custom widget will just sit in
>   the  queue until the long running task completes and control is
>   allowed to  return to the main loop.  Adding the yield allows those
>   events to be  processed sooner, but you may still have problems when
>   the long running  task does finally run because any new events that
>   need to be processed  during that time (for example, the user clicks a
>   Cancel button) will  still have to wait until the LRT is finished.
>
> Another issue to watch out for when using a yield function is that it 
>   could lead to an unexpected recursion.  For example you have a LRT
>   that  periodically calls yield so events can be processed, but one of
>   the  events that happens is one whose event handler starts the LRT
>   again.
>
> So usually it is better to use some other way to prevent blocking of 
>   events while running a the LRT, such as breaking it up into chunks
>   that  are run from EVT_IDLE handlers, or using a thread.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any threads in the code you show, so it's really not clear why do you think this has anything to do with threading. Quite the contrary, in fact: AFAICS this is due to *not* using threads. You should run your long running ("intensive") code in a worker thread, then things would work and display correctly in the UI.

You can't block the main, UI thread for any non-trivial amount of time and still expect the UI to update correctly.

Comment: Agreed, but that still doesn't explain the situation. I have a sequence of commands `A-B-C-D`. What is happening is that the commands perform in this order: `B-C-D-A`, where `A` is the initialization of a new `wx.Frame`. I'm wondering why `A` isn't appearing when I call it, and instead performing other tasks before finally executing.

Comment: If you're using wxGTK, then showing (realizing) a new frame is a complex operation involving some delays. It usually doesn't matter as long as the event loop is running however.

Comment: Hm, I'm on 64-bit macOS, which I believe defaults to wxOSX/Cocoa, not wxGTK

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why does the frame show up only later under macOS.